# Power BI DAX ALL function confusion

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently studying Power BI and DAX and I would like to understand the fundamentals as much as possible.

I am now at ALL() function. I have good understanding about it however I am a bit confused how it behaves in Power BI in one scenario, such as below.
[image]

Table 1 and 2 are TestFact and TestDim respectively, and they relate via shiptypeid.

Using Cnt on Table 3, it gives me 4 rows. However using the CntAll in Table 4, it gives me 12 rows. It's as if it does not use the relationship on shiptypeid. My expectation is just still 4 rows but 4 for all rows.

Table 5 is the same with Table 4 but I have removed the shiptype column, and viola it gives me 4 rows. So I am thinking this likely this is due to relationship. But why is this happening? Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are creating a measure that calculates the same value no matter what `shiptype` you use, since you are lifting any filters incoming to `TestFact` from `TestDim` (and any other sources) when you use `ALL()`.

This causes your table visualisation to expand (perhaps not intuitively) because for your first row: `orderid = 8000, shipmentid = 1001`, all the different ship types will have a "valid" row count in `TestFact`.

Whenever you use this `CntAll` measure with dimensions from `TestDim`, all the distinct combinations from `TestDim` will crossjoin with all distinct combinations from `TestFact`.

[image]

When you remove the `shiptype` column you will be left with only the distinct combinations from `TestFact`, which will result in 4 rows.

Comment: That is what I suspected as well. Thanks for the reply. Appreciate it!